# Call an activity within a timer

Tags: android, android-activity

In my main activity I create an object internetCheck. My class checkInternet:

```
public class internetCheck {

private Timer myTimer;


public void launchTime(final Context context){
    myTimer = new Timer();
    Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        boolean conn = false;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!check(context)){
                if(!conn) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.activity, MainActivity.class);
                            MainActivity.activity.startActivity(i);

                    conn=true;
                    System.out.println("déconnection" + conn);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            }
            else{
                conn = false;
                System.out.println("déconnection" + conn);

            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}



public boolean check(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(null != netInfo){
        if(netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        }
        if(netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            return true;
        }
    }
   return false;
}
}
```

After creation I call the launchTime method which create a timer. I want to go back to my MainActivity when internet is down. Everything works fine but I can't go back to the MainActivity. I don't know why my startActivity(i) doesn't work

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a hint. You are creating an instance of handler, but never using it. You should use hanlder.postDelayed (e.g) instead of timer. (Timer -> Java, Handler -> Android).

Comment: I tried lot of things, this handler is a rest of these tests. I can't use postDelayed, cause I don't want to do this action after a certain time, I want that the timer continues to work after this change.

Comment: Well ok. But you could also recall postDelayed in your Runnable :)

Comment: You mean, use a postDelayed wich call himself when it stops?

Comment: Yep, but TimerTask is fine. I assume by the way, that you can't start an activity from itself. My assumption would be, that you should write a service for your wanted behaviour or register as a receiver for internetconnection in every activity. Either way, to create a timer, check connectivity and return to the main activity is not the way you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the activity via the context you have available:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
ctx.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I tried to do it but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Tartempion34 from where do you call `launchTime()`?

Comment: From the onCreate() of the MainActivity

Comment: @Tartempion34 what do you expect to happen when you start `MainActivity` from `MainActivity`?

Comment: from MainActivity, nothing, but the timer works after the user changes activity